# Thread Creation with Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, autowired

I am new to Spring and trying to implement a multi threaded program. As per Spring documentation in this link, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html, threads can be created like,

```
public class TaskExecutorExample {
  private class MessagePrinterTask implements Runnable {
    private String message;
    public MessagePrinterTask(String message) {
      this.message = message;
    }
    public void run() {
      System.out.println(message);
    }
  }

  private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
  public TaskExecutorExample(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
  }
  public void printMessages() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      taskExecutor.execute(new MessagePrinterTask("Message" + i));
    }
  }
}
```

But the 'Thread' is created with a 'new' keyword and the bean is not managed by Spring. Hence it cannot access any Autowired components. A work around to this problem can be to Autowire the component in the outside class and pass it to the thread class in its constructor.

But is there any other proper way of doing this, where Spring can take care of initializing the threads, so that the threads can have access to all auto wired components.

The application I am creating will have to create a new thread for every new message it receives from a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the questions is about the way to init the TaskExecutor and use it?! So, the docs show the way to do that:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutorExample" class="TaskExecutorExample">
  <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

Or you can do in your Code using `@Bean` like

```
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(5);
        pool.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        pool.setQueueCapacity(25);
        return pool; 
    }

  @Bean
  public TaskExecutorExample executorExample() {
    return new TaskExecutorExample(threadPool());
  }
```

Then you can `@Autowired` to use it.
About the details of `corePoolSize`, `maxPoolSize`, `queueCapacity`, you can refer here: http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size

**EDIT1**: after have the clarification from Samo, I'd like to update it to:

Add @Component to your Thread with the @Scope("prototype"). Then use @Autowired your Thread and execute taskExecutor.execute(sampleThread)

Sample in here: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/ Part: 3. Spring Thread Pool + Spring managed bean example

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi. My question was on how to create a thread when submitting it to the thread pool. If you use 'new Thread()' to create one and then submit it to the thread pool, then Spring does not manage the thread object that we created. So how to we create a instance of thread so that it will be managed by spring.

Comment: Just add `@Component` to your Thread with the `@Scope("prototype")`. Then you can `@Autowired` your Thread and execute `taskExecutor.execute(sampleThread)` like this.

Comment: @samo: just incase you still need to refer the sample. Pls see 3. Spring Thread Pool + Spring managed bean example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/